# How can I make an object randomly move side to side in pygame?

Tags: pygame

Is it possible for a 2D object in pygame to constantly move side to side randomly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

A good way to do this would be to give it speed, direction, and duration of the speed .Every cycle change the position of the object based on the direction and speed, and decrease the duration, when the duration is 0 generate a new speed and direction for your object.